# Select statement scope

Tags: go

In Go, I know that every new enclosing braces declare a new scope, this is true of all control flow statements. Today while writing a program, I stumbled in a scenario where I needed to use the `select` statement like below

```
select {
case <-ctx.Done():
    <-ch
    return ctx.Err()
case resp := <-ch:
    var b bytes.Buffer
    if _, err := io.Copy(&b, resp.Body); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

From the above code, I would like to access the `b` variable after select statement is closed. Will that be possible?

I know I can move the logic that uses `b` inside the select, but I would rather not go that route because `select` is much complicated already on its own and want to keep it slim for easy understanding in future.

Comment: Just move the `var b` declaration before `select`?

Comment: Declare `b` in the scope that encompasses all uses of `b`.  It sounds like the scope is outside of the select statement.

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ What if I shadow `b` by assigning to it inside `select` statement

Comment: Hm, could you show example code for what you mean? @CholthiPaulTtiopic

Comment: Just try it out. No need to get fancy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely fine to declare a `var` outside the `select` if it's intended to be used after the `select`:

```
var b bytes.Buffer
select {
case <-ctx.Done():
    <-ch
    return ctx.Err()
case resp := <-ch:
    if _, err := io.Copy(&b, resp.Body); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
... // use b here
```

There is no shadowing involved here, and you can't shadow unless you have another `b` declared in an inner scope. An assignment `b = <something>` inside the select here will just assign to the right `b`.